# How to better express the ambiguous meaning in "Write me when you are back"

Tags: ambiguity

The phrase *"Write me when you are back"* has ambiguous meaning. It might mean - *write me the day you have arrived* or *write me when you are planning to be back*. What is the minimal addition/change in the phrase so that it's not ambiguous anymore.

Comment: When you're back, write me. / When do you get back?

Comment: The sentence would not be interpreted to have either of the two meanings you think it has. It means **neither** of those things. Rather, it means: *Once you have returned, write to me.*

Comment: @verbose Prior context would determine exactly what 'back' meant in this sentence. As with my rewrites. But I agree, the question isn't great.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't understand your comment. Whatever *back* means in the original sentence, *when you are back* unambiguously means *upon your return*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Precisely. I still don't understand the purport of your comments in response to mine. To clarify, my first comment was directed at the OP, not at your first comment (which hit about a second before mine). I meant that I do not think the OP's original sentence could carry either of the two meanings the OP believes it could. And I'm wondering why you think I need the meaning of *when you are back* explained to me.

Comment: @verbose 'back' is a deictic indexical: 'I know you're returning home to the States next week. I'll miss you. When you are back, write me.' // 'I know you're returning to Oldham next week: it will be good to see you again. When you are back ...'. Yes, 'Once you have returned, write to me.' covers both these situations, but so does 'Write me when you are back'. Your 'The sentence would not be interpreted to have either of the two meanings you think it has.' is not correct.

Comment: The sentence is not used to express the second meaning.

Answer (score 0):

She went to Brazil for two years, but now **she's back** (=[has returned](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/back) ).

*She is back = She has returned.*

But normally a simple present tense in the 'when-clause' has a future reference.

So, 'when your are back' means 'once you have returned' (in future).

'Write (to) me after you have returned' won't create any ambiguity.